# Return key from final object pushed into an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Trying to return the last key from an object pushed into an array

```
var remove = function(s, k) {
   let stack = [];
   let newObj = {}; 
   for(const char of s){
    let letter = stack[stack.length-1]
    console.log(`stack: ${stack[stack.length-1][0]}`)
    if(char !== letter){
        newObj[char] = newObj[char] ? newObj[char]+1 : 1
[Object.values(newObj).length-1])
        stack.push({newObj})
    } 
    else if(char === letter && Object.values(newObj)[Object.values(newObj).length-1]){
        stack.pop()
    }
    }
}
```

If I pass in

```
const s = "deeedbbcccbdaa"; 
const k = 3;
```

I expect my console.logs to retun the last letter I pushed into the array. However this is what I'm seeing currently:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Comment: Can you please restructure code a little bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

```
let text = "deeedbbcccbdaa";
const myArray = text.split("");

console.log(myArray[myArray.unshift()-1])
```

[Try it](https://jsbin.com/zobonorela/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because before you enter the `for` loop, you assign `stack` to an empty array (`let stack = []`).

This means that on the first iteration of your `for` loop, you are trying to access the last element of stack in your `console.log` statement, even though it doesn't exist yet.

In other words, the first time your `for` loop runs, `stack[stack.length-1]` is undefined. So the error comes from trying to access index 0 of this value.

Hope that helps!